# Deploying UWP app to Windows 10 Mobile device fails

Tags: device, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to deploy a UWP app to a Lumia 640 running Windows 10.0.10572.0. My desktop is running Windows 10 Pro (non-beta) and Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. Both the desktop and phone are set to "Developer mode", and the phone's "Save Location" is set to "This Device".

When I create a new UWP app in VS and attempt to deploy it to the phone (ARM) I get the error:

`Error : DEP4100 : The folder "C:\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\fd452efe-5984-4038-8a9f-0e07c53cc89fVS.Debug_ARM.Tom" could not be created. 
Access to the path 'C:\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\fd452efe-5984-4038-8a9f-0e07c53cc89fVS.Debug_ARM.Tom' is denied.`

Has anyone been able to successfully deploy a UWP app to a phone and debug it?

Thanks! -Tom B.

Comment: You can try updating Windows SDK and the emulator. Check out [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3f1a4a71-f402-44e9-b18e-f6b2e41796d0/uwp-mobilebuild10572deploymentdeployment-fails-on-phone-build-10572?forum=wpdevelop) thread for more info -

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the phone to the fast ring update that came out yesterday (Windows 10 Mobile 10.0.10581.0) I am now able to deploy and debug on it. Hooray!

Comment: I am using 10.0.586 and still have the problem. After install the Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, my emulators changed to 10.0.586 and I couldn't debug on it too. My workaround was, build the app and use the Windows Phone Application Deployment to deploy it.

Answer (score -2):

Finally got a program to debug on my 950XL. It appears that having the 8.1 SDK on the machine and running the new Update choosing to update the 8.1 bit is the key.

**Microsoft: please fix so that having the Windows 10 UWP by itself allows one to debug to a Windows 10 Mobile device!!!!!!!!**